# RealityKit – Dragged Object Switches Planes

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

How to develop this function?

When the user drags the ModelEntity, the ModelEntity can switch planes.

Look at this [demo video](https://youtu.be/JtEFEV4fFYo).

Answer (score 3):

You should use **ray-casting** instance methods to get the desired behavior:

```
@IBOutlet var arView: ARView!

guard let raycastQuery = arView.makeRaycastQuery(from: arView.center,   // CGPoint
                                             allowing: .estimatedPlane, // Target
                                            alignment: .horizontal)     // TargetAlignment
else { return }

// This method checks once for intersections between a ray and real-world surfaces
guard let raycastResult = arView.session.raycast(raycastQuery).first
else { return }

let worldTransform = Transform(matrix: raycastResult.worldTransform)    // simd_float4x4

let anchor = AnchorEntity(raycastResult: raycastResult)
// yourModel.transform = worldTransform
// or...
// anchor.transform = worldTransform

anchor.addChild(yourModel)
arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
```

Comment: Hi @Andy Jazz, this is not working for me as expected. Is there any other way? Shouldn't this happen automatically?

Comment: @Nishu_Priya, I've added two lines of code after `anchor` declaration.